# winapi mouse_event HWHEEL not working

Tags: c#, winapi, mouseevent

I would like to know why HWHEEL is not working in some programs? For example it's working in Chrome, but not working in Eclipse or explorer...

```
mouse_event((int)MouseEventFlagsAPI.HWHEEL, 0, 0, 120, 0);
```

When I try to scroll with touchpad it's working.
Also, is there a programmatic solution that works?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of applications ignore WM_MOUSEHWHEEL.  Mice with horizontal scroll wheels are pretty rare.  Touchpad drivers generally don't generate WM_MOUSEHWHEEL, and scroll using other methods.

Comment: Actually, most mice generate `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL`. They don't have horizontal wheels, but if you push the wheel to left or right you'll find it clicks. That's an H scroll. But what you say is quite right. Many programs ignore it.

Comment: So, what is then solution for horizontal scroll? What are the methods that touchpad drivers use?

Comment: Can't speak for the touchpad driver writers; they tend to do strange, undocumented, and application-specific things.  You might want to look at [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684021(v=vs.85).aspx) and [IUIAutomationScrollPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee696180(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: IUIAutomationScrollPattern supports only XP SP3, I need support for SP2 also. Tried with SHIFT + mouse_event(VERTICAL_WHEEL, 0, 0, 120, 0) but without success.